# Return empty string instead of null in SpringBoot Web response

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to get an empty string instead of null in the response from a HTTP rest controller in a Spring Boot Web project.

The return code is as follows: an ArrayNode class wrapped into ResponseEntity

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
```

The image below shows that it is a NullNode in the response and the second image shows the response in Postman. I would like the contactNumber field to be empty string instead of null.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must define your own CustomNullStringSerializerProvider and call him in your ObjectMapper

https://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2015/03/18/how-to-make-jackson-serialize-null-strings-differently-than-null-objects/

Josselin